# How to locate and get text from a tooltip in webdriverIO

Tags: webdriver-io

I am trying to locate a tooltip within a div, and then extract the tooltip-text which is visible when I do mouse hover over the tooltip. Copying below the code snapshot from UI --

```
<div id="18792650D23511E48900E8F9867BF357__dorpdown_div" title="" data-original-title="This action is only available from the published version of this offering.">
<li id="18792650D23511E48900E8F9867BF357_Create_Next_Version_dorpdown_items" class="disabledMenuItem">
<a id="18792650D23511E48900E8F9867BF357_Create_Next_Version" href="javascript:void(0)">Create Next Version</a>
</li>
</div>
```

I am trying with getAttribute() function, below is the code

```
webDriver.waitForExist(element_createNextVersionTooltip);
    var tooltip = webDriver.getAttribute(element_createNextVersionTooltip, 'data-original-title');
    browser.moveToObject(element_createNextVersionTooltip.pause(500).)
    console.log("**tooltip ** : ", + tooltip);
```

But when i run the testcase, it returns NaN.

Is there any other approach to execute this ?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code in the question not linked as an image.

Comment: I have added the code snippet in a correct format. Please help me with this issue.